# C++: static vars not persisting between files

Tags: c++

I have a config.h file with a bunch of constants.
in main.cpp, it sets one of the constants to some value, and then calls a function in util.cpp.

util.cpp also has config.h included, but the variable set by main.cpp does not have the same value.

Code:

config.h:

```
static int MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRAINING_DATA = 1000;
```

main.cpp (main):

```
else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-mTrnData") == 0)
            {
                MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRAINING_DATA = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
            cout << "Number of data sets to be generated: " << MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRAINING_DATA << "\n\n";
                          // prints what I tell it
            }
```

and in utils.cpp

```
cout << "Number of data sets generated: " << MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRAINING_DATA << "\n\n";
    // prints the default value (in this case, 1000)
```

So, how do I fix this so that I can have my config.h file of constants be remembered throughout my cpp files?

In Java, you can do Config.NAME_OF_CONSTANT , so, if there is a way to do that in C++, that would be most grand.

I know constants aren't supposed to change, but the only time they do change is in main() when reading in the arguments from the running the program... after that they don't change.

Comment: A variable that changes values can hardly be considered a *constant*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each translation unit receives its own copy of `static` data.

The easiest way to verify this is to print the address of `MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRAINING_DATA` in both units - it will be different. To avoid it, declare it `extern` in the header and define it once in one unit, for example in `main.cpp`.

Apart from that is it evil to have such global variables (whose naming scheme even suggests that we're talking about constants!). You might consider to refactor the code, for example use a getter `GetMaxNumberOfTrainingData()` to make the value available while keeping write access to it restricted to a single unit.

Comment: But without using getters and setters: in Java, you could do something like Config.NAME_OF_CONSTANT, is there a way to do this in C++? 

I'm calling them constants, because aside from the arguments changing them, they don't change afterwards.

Comment: @DerNalia There's nothing stopping you from creating a container class to store your static variables, but you'll still have the same issues unless you use setters and getters.

Answer (score 4):

A non-const `static` variable at namespace scope in a header file is
almost certainly an error.  You get an instance of the variable for each
file that includes the file.  If you want to use the same variable in
several different translation units, declare it `extern` (and without
the initializer) in the header, and then define it (without the
`extern`, although you can also use the `extern` if there is an
initializer) in a single source file.

Answer (score 1):

A static variable has a "file scope" by definition. So by declaring it in a header file, every .c file that includes it gets its own variable. They have nothing to do with each other.

You should genereally never declare variables in header files. If you need a variable in multiple modules, declare it in one file and add them as extern in all other files you need it.

Answer (score 0):

From a design point of view, you should switch to a `Configuration` or `Option` object.

Each class would depend on an instance of this object to be provided, and you could have different initializations routines: from a file, from command line, etc...

Better yet, you would avoid the global variables!